# Text input value like option tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know how to put it into the context. I really hope my code will explain the condition.

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <span>
    <label>Auto Complete</label>
      <input type="text" id="tags" name="text" value=""/>
  </span>
</fieldset>
```

How to make the text input displays the complete option from js, but the value only like id1, id2, id3? is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by: '*but the value only like id1, id2, id3?*'?

Comment: What is problem or error you are getting here?

Comment: In case you want to show one text, but pass different value to server, then I guess you should use `select` tag instead of `text input` then. Look into libraries like select2 or chosen

Comment: Create an array of objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <input list="tag">

    <datalist id="tag">
        <option value="ActionScript">
        <option value="AppleScript">
        <option value="Asp">
        <option value="BASIC">
        <option value="C">
        <option value="C++">
        <option value="Clojure">
        <option value="COBOL">
        <option value="ColdFusion">
        <option value="Erlang">
        <option value="Etc.">
    </datalist>
```